# Показать div при клике на кнопку -> Ошибка

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку блок изменял `display:none;` на `display:block;`.
Есть такой код :

```js
function floatW() {
            var floatWindow = document.getElementById("floatWindow");
            floatWindow.style.display = "block";
        }
```

```css
.floatWindow
{
    display : none ;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background : red;
    margin: 200px 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="floatWindow" about="bttn"></div>
<input type="button" name="" id="textCol" value="Text color" onclick="floatW()" />
```

Comment: Серьезно, вы не отличаете `id` от класса?

Comment: ааааа , вот *** не заметил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправьте id="floatWindow и стиль соответственно на #floatWindow